# \refcite does not produce hyperlink and does not work in figure caption (World Scientific documentclass)

Tags: captions, citing, document-classes, hyperlink

I'm using the ws-procs961x669 documentclass by World Scientific. I'm having two problems with the command "\refcite{}" that is meant to be used when explicitly referring to a reference to print its number in the text:

1. Unlike the command "\cite{}", it does not produce a clickable hyperlink.
2. Unlike the command "\cite{}", it does not seem to work in captions of figures and tables, see below.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{ws-procs961x669}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    This produces a hyperlink\cite{aa}. Unfortunately, referring directly to Ref.~\refcite{aa} does not produce a hyperlink. 

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{The results presented in this figure are stolen from Ref.~\cite{aa}.}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

% This produces a compilation error
%\begin{figure}[!htbp]
%  \centering
%  \caption{The results presented in this figure are stolen from Ref.~\refcite{aa}.}
%  \label{fig:fig2}
%\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem{aa} A.\ Author, \textit{Stop stealing my results}, published in \textit{The Journal of dubious results} (2021).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you "allowed" to modify the `ws-procs961x669` document class? I am assuming that you want to submit an article. Maybe this is intended behavior (why not use the cite command instead?

Comment: I'm using "\cite{}" for the most part, but as I've explained in my post above and you've correctly pointed out in your answer below, "\refcite{}" should be used when the citation forms part of a sentence. In my case, one of those instances happens to occur inside of a figure caption. In any case, it would be nice if all instances of "\refcite{}" also link to the corresponding bibliography entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved: I found the command `\citenum{}`, which seems to do exactly what `\refcite{}` does, but also works in captions of figures/tables and produces hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

- Not an answer but too long for a comment.
- [This](https://worldscientific.com/sda/1020/procs-instruction961x669_2e.pdf) it [this](https://worldscientific.com/sda/1037/ws-bme.pdf) seems to be the instructions for the [document class](https://worldscientific.com/page/authors/proceedings-stylefiles).
- According to my understanding, the command `\cite{name}` is used to create superscript-like citations, see screenshot "Golub".
- `\refcite{name}` is used when the citation is part of the sentence as in "Ref. 2 shows that [...]".

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]